# Identify regression groups

Tags: regression, clustering

I have time series data with some value and corresponding time. These measurements are divided into groups (I plotted each group in a separate plot). I want to build a linear regression model for each group. The problem is that some groups can be divided into subgroups by time (after some reset) and you can make a regression for each of these subgroups. In this case, I am only interested in the regression of the last subgroup. How can I identify these subgroups or get the regression of the last subgroup? The regression is always negative. I come to the solution of finding differences between neighboring values and time points and looking for outliers to identify the jump between groups, but I'm not sure how robust this method is.

[image]